# 'SyntaxError invalid syntax' when adding column with if condition to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a new column `dfout['EXCHANGE_RATIO']` whose values (rows) will be taken from another dataframe (`dfc['EXCHANGE_RATIO']`) only when `dfout['CURRENCY'] != 'EUR'`. When `dfout['CURRENCY'] != 'EUR'` I search for that value in `dfc['CURRENCY_SOURCE']` and I take the  value of `dfc['EXCHANGE_RATIO']` in that same row.

`dfout` looks like this:

```
                DATE_PROCESS  BOOKING_ID DEP_AIRPORT ARR_AIRPORT       DEPARTURE_DATE         ARRIVAL_DATE    PRICE CURRENCY
0    2013-04-19 16:04:13 UTC    76969972         AEL         DEL  2013-04-18 00:00:00                  NaN   409.04      EUR
1    2014-04-17 02:26:46 UTC    76888867         ARP         ZAL  2014-04-19 00:00:00                  NaN   280.70      EUR
```

`dfc` looks like this:

```
    CURRENCY_SOURCE CURRENCY_TARGET  EXCHANGE_RATIO
0               TRL             EUR    9.900000e-08
1               VES             EUR    3.220000e-07
```

I've tried these 2 ways and both throw out `Syntax error: invalid syntax`. Why?

```py
dfout['EXCHANGE_RATIO'] = dfout['CURRENCY'].apply(lambda x: dfc.query('CURRENCY_SOURCE'==x)['EXCHANGE_RATIO'] if x != 'EUR')

dfout['EXCHANGE_RATIO'] = dfout['CURRENCY'].apply(lambda x: dfc.loc[dfc['CURRENCY_SOURCE'] == x, 'EXCHANGE_RATIO'].iloc[-1] if x != 'EUR')
```

Comment: It needs `else` too

Comment: @MustafaAydın yes. I've just added `else` and now they're failing for other reasons. I'm looking at it and will update my post when I find what is happening.

Comment: There are multiple rows with ````EUR```` in ````dfc```` right? How do you chose which exchange_ratio to pick?

Comment: @sharathnatraj I made a mistake in my post, I just corrected it. I search in `dfc['CURRENCY_SOURCE']`. There's no row with `EUR` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) method:

```
dfout['EXCHANGE_RATIO'] = dfout['CURRENCY'] \
    .map(dict(zip(dfc['CURRENCY_SOURCE'], dfc['EXCHANGE_RATIO'])))
```

for example with a `dfout` like this:

```
              DATE_PROCESS  BOOKING_ID DEP_AIRPORT ARR_AIRPORT       DEPARTURE_DATE  ARRIVAL_DATE   PRICE CURRENCY
0  2013-04-19 16:04:13 UTC    76969972         AEL         DEL  2013-04-18 00:00:00           NaN  409.04      EUR
1  2014-04-17 02:26:46 UTC    76888867         ARP         ZAL  2014-04-19 00:00:00           NaN  280.70      EUR
2  2014-04-17 02:26:46 UTC    76888867         ARP         ZAL  2014-04-19 00:00:00           NaN  280.70      TRL
3  2014-04-17 02:26:46 UTC    76888867         ARP         ZAL  2014-04-19 00:00:00           NaN  280.70      VES
```

you would get the following output:

```
              DATE_PROCESS  BOOKING_ID DEP_AIRPORT ARR_AIRPORT       DEPARTURE_DATE  ARRIVAL_DATE   PRICE CURRENCY  EXCHANGE_RATIO
0  2013-04-19 16:04:13 UTC    76969972         AEL         DEL  2013-04-18 00:00:00           NaN  409.04      EUR             NaN
1  2014-04-17 02:26:46 UTC    76888867         ARP         ZAL  2014-04-19 00:00:00           NaN  280.70      EUR             NaN
2  2014-04-17 02:26:46 UTC    76888867         ARP         ZAL  2014-04-19 00:00:00           NaN  280.70      TRL    9.900000e-08
3  2014-04-17 02:26:46 UTC    76888867         ARP         ZAL  2014-04-19 00:00:00           NaN  280.70      VES    3.220000e-07
```

and if you want to replace those `NaN` you can use `fillna()`:

```
dfout['EXCHANGE_RATIO'] = dfout['CURRENCY'] \
    .map(dict(zip(dfc['CURRENCY_SOURCE'], dfc['EXCHANGE_RATIO']))) \
    .fillna(1)  # or whatever you want there
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected the `query` syntax and added `else` to make your code work. You have to call the `x` with the `@`.

```
dfout['EXCHANGE_RATIO'] = dfout['CURRENCY'].apply(lambda x: dfc.query('CURRENCY_SOURCE==@x')['EXCHANGE_RATIO'][0] if x != 'EUR' else np.NaN)
```

dfout - input

```
                                DATE_PROCESS    BOOKING_ID  DEP_AIRPORT ARR_AIRPORT DEPARTURE_DATE  ARRIVAL_DATE    PRICE   CURRENCY
0   2013-04-19  16:04:13    UTC 76969972        AEL         DEL         2013-04-18  00:00:00        NaN             409.04  EUR
1   2014-04-17  02:26:46    UTC 76888867        ARP         ZAL         2014-04-19  00:00:00        NaN             280.70  EUR
2   2014-04-17  02:26:46    UTC 76888867        ARP         ZAL         2014-04-19  00:00:00        NaN             280.70  TRL
```

dfc

```
  CURRENCY_SOURCE CURRENCY_TARGET  EXCHANGE_RATIO
0             TRL             EUR    9.900000e-08
1             VES             EUR    3.220000e-07
```

dfout - Output

```
                                DATE_PROCESS    BOOKING_ID  DEP_AIRPORT ARR_AIRPORT DEPARTURE_DATE  ARRIVAL_DATE    PRICE   CURRENCY    EXCHANGE_RATIO
0   2013-04-19  16:04:13    UTC 76969972        AEL         DEL         2013-04-18  00:00:00        NaN             409.04  EUR         NaN
1   2014-04-17  02:26:46    UTC 76888867        ARP         ZAL         2014-04-19  00:00:00        NaN             280.70  EUR         NaN
2   2014-04-17  02:26:46    UTC 76888867        ARP         ZAL         2014-04-19  00:00:00        NaN             280.70  TRL         9.900000e-08
```